# Search different columns in MySQL Join

Tags: mysql, database

I am using the below query to extract and sort data from 2 different tables.

```
SELECT 
  users.*,
  story.*,
  IFNULL(share.`date`, story.`date`) AS sort_date 
FROM
  users 
  INNER JOIN story 
    ON users.id = story.user_id 
  LEFT JOIN SHARE 
    ON share.story_id = story.id 
WHERE story.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
  AND story.title LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%' 
ORDER BY sort_date DESC
```

Its working great but I need to search in multiple columns on 2 tables like below

```
SELECT 
  users.*,
  story.*,
  IFNULL(share.`date`, story.`date`) AS sort_date 
FROM
  users 
  INNER JOIN story 
    ON users.id = story.user_id 
  LEFT JOIN SHARE 
    ON share.story_id = story.id 
WHERE story.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
  AND story.title LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%' 
  AND users.name LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%' 
ORDER BY sort_date DESC
```

Now this doesn't work :(

Comment: not working as in what? means throwing error or result not returned?

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected results.

Comment: Try this and inform if it works for: Change `AND` to `OR` in `AND users.name LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%'`

Answer (score 0):

After `WHERE`, you have to specify a *single* condition, not two or three or more.

This condition can be constructed from simpler conditions using [logical operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective) such as AND, OR, XOR, NOT.

For example the AND operator joins two conditions in such a way that the resulting condition is true only if both of the operands are true. So when you say

```
story.title LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%' AND users.name LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%'
```

this is true for results in which both `story.title LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%'` and `users.name LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%'` are true. This is most likely not what you want. In contrast,

```
story.title LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%' OR users.name LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%'
```

is true for results in which `story.title LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%'` is true and for results in which `users.name LIKE '%SEARCH_TERM%'` is true.